# MPI_Scatterv segmentation error even if I got right result

Tags: c++, c, mpi

I was trying to use MPI doing some parallel work like counting triangles on a network graph. And in order to let each process compute same amount of times, I use scatterv to distribute different data into different processes. Here is my code:

```
MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
int i, j, k, v1, v2, vertices;
struct Graph *g;
int *n;
int rank, size;

// Build the Graph from the input file
f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
fscanf(f, "%d", &vertices);
g = createGraph(vertices);
while ((fscanf(f, "%d%d", &v1, &v2)) != EOF) {
    addEdge(g, v1, v2);
}

fclose(f);

n = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * vertices);

for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
    n[i] = i;
}

createNeighborSets(g);
printf("create graph\n");

int sendcount[size];
int offset[size];
int count = 0;
int *localVertices;
int localNum;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Request request;

if (rank == 0) {

    calculateDistribution(send count, offset);

    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
       MPI_Send(&sendcount[i], 1, MPI_INT, i, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    localNum = sendcount[0];
} else {
    MPI_Recv(&localNum, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 3, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
}

localVertices = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * localNum);
MPI_Scatterv(n, sendcount, offset, MPI_INT, localVertices, localNum, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

When I run my code, the error message is like this:

```
[MacBook-Pro-7:96512] *** Process received signal ***
[MacBook-Pro-7:96512] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11) 
[MacBook-Pro-7:96512] Signal code:  (0)
[MacBook-Pro-7:96512] Failing at address: 0x0
[MacBook-Pro-7:96512] [ 0] [MacBook-Pro-7:96513] *** Process received signal ***
[MacBook-Pro-7:96513] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[MacBook-Pro-7:96513] Signal code:  (0)
[MacBook-Pro-7:96513] Failing at address: 0x0
[MacBook-Pro-7:96513] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff633b4f5a _sigtramp + 26 
[MacBook-Pro-7:96513] [ 1] [MacBook-Pro-7:96510] *** Process received signal ***
[MacBook-Pro-7:96510] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[MacBook-Pro-7:96510] Signal code:  (0)
[MacBook-Pro-7:96510] Failing at address: 0x0
[MacBook-Pro-7:96510] [ 0] 0   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00007fff633b4f5a _sigtramp + 26
[MacBook-Pro-7:96510] [ 1] 0   ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
```

When I output the value of localVertices after the scatterv, I found that my threads have already got the right member, but the error occurred before further work with the triangle counting.

Comment: Can you get a clean stack trace ? As a side note, you can use `MPI_Scatter()` to distribute `sendcount`. You should also check `malloc()` does nor return `NULL`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (read the page very carefully).